# How can you restrict certain apps from launching on Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to build a sandboxed environment in which only certain apps are allowed to be launched.

I had originally decided to try polling all running apps in the background to see which ones were running, then killing any that weren't on the whtielist. However, I discovered that you can only kill background processes, not active tasks.

If this can be done, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to do this is if you have the platform signing key. If you implement an "activity watcher" (which requires android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER, which requires being signed by the platform signing key), you get notified before a new activity is started, and you can prevent it from starting.

There isn't any way to do this generically because it would give malicious code way too much freedom.

Answer (score 0):

Seems unlikely that you can do this with any sort of reliability from an app if you're trying to do this for security reasons. If you're serious enough, you could probably customize the OS itself seeing as Android is open source, but that's a fairly involved undertaking. Any specifics on why you're trying to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to build a sandboxed environment in which only certain apps are allowed to be launched.

Write your own firmware.

Or, as a stopgap, write your own home screen that does not provide access to the Settings app, so you can prevent applications from being installed. Savvy users will reboot the device in safe mode and return to the firmware's home screen, which is why the real solution is to write your own firmware.